# Symfony2: Convert Entitytype to Checkboxes / Radiobutton

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

For my Symfony Project I am using a form which gets its field-data from another chart. The data itself is shown correctly but there are some problems with the booking-field (Booking) and the field for room-equipment (Zimmerausstattung).

[Form with EntityType](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15J3D.jpg)

My Form code:

```
class ZimmerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('zimmerNummer', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Zimmer: ', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Nr. oder Name')))
            ->add('betten', IntegerType::class, array('label' => 'Betten: *', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Anzahl der Betten')))
            ->add('standort', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Standort: ', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Etage oder Ort des Zimmers')))
            ->add('zimmerausstattung', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Zimmerausstattung: ',
                                                                'class' => 'AppBundle:Zimmerausstattung',
                                                                'multiple'    => true,
                                                                'required'    => false,
                                                                'empty_data'  => null,
                                                                ))
            ->add('location', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Location: *', 
                                                       'class' => 'AppBundle:Location'))
            ->add('booking', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Booking: ',
                                                                'class' => 'AppBundle:Booking',
                                                                'multiple' => true,
                                                                'required'    => false,
                                                                'empty_data'  => null,
                                                                ))

        ;
    }
```

I converted the whole form into "Checkbutton / Radiobutton" - and although the convertion is working fine there aren´t any Records shown.

[Form with Checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiEUU.jpg)

```
class ZimmerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('zimmerNummer', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Zimmer: ', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Nr. oder Name')))
            ->add('betten', IntegerType::class, array('label' => 'Betten: *', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Anzahl der Betten')))
            ->add('standort', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Standort: ', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Etage oder Ort des Zimmers')))
            ->add('zimmerausstattung', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Zimmerausstattung: ',
                                                                'class' => 'AppBundle:Zimmerausstattung',
                                                                'multiple'    => true,
                                                                'required'    => false,
                                                                'empty_data'  => null,))
                                                                'expanded'    => true,))
            ->add('location', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Location: *', 
                                                       'class' => 'AppBundle:Location'))
            ->add('booking', EntityType::class, array('label' => 'Booking: ',
                                                                'class' => 'AppBundle:Booking',
                                                                'multiple' => true,
                                                                'required'    => false,
                                                                'empty_data'  => null,
                                                                'choice_label' => 'person.name',
                                                                'expanded'    => true,
                                                                ))

        ;
    }
```

My Twig-Code:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme edit_form 'form_table_layout.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Zimmer {{ entity.zimmernummer }} bearbeiten {% endblock %}
{% block body -%}
<h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>

{{ form(edit_form) }}

    <ul class="record_actions">
<li>
    <a href="{{ path('zimmer') }}">
        Zurück zur Übersicht
    </a>
</li>
<li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I solve this problem?
It would be very nice if somebody could help me with this problem cause I am running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `choice_label` which refer to objects parameter.  Example: `'choice_label' => 'title'` where `title` is yours entity field.

Docs:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choice-label

Comment: Thank you it works now. But the problem was the twig-template.

Comment: glad you found the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

My final solution:

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}Zimmer {{ entity.zimmernummer }} bearbeiten {% endblock %}

{% block body -%}
<h1>{{ block('title') }}</h1>

<table>
{{ form_start(edit_form) }}
<tr>
<td>{{ form_label(edit_form.zimmerNummer) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form.zimmerNummer) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_label(edit_form.betten) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form.betten) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_label(edit_form.standort) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form.standort) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_label(edit_form.zimmerausstattung) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form.zimmerausstattung) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>{{ form_label(edit_form.location) }}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form.location) }}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> {# empty #}</td>
<td>{{ form_widget(edit_form) }}</td>
</tr>
{{ form_end(edit_form) }}
</table>

<ul class="record_actions">
<li>
<a href="{{ path('zimmer') }}">Zurück zur Übersicht</a></li>
<li>{{ form(delete_form) }}</li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```